# How to add single twitter feed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a single (last one) twitter feed in my html template. But when I paste twitter script from twitter then I see that there is a thumbnails type twitter post.Is there any way to add single twitter in html ? How ? I am using bootstrap for html coding.

Thanks advance. :)

Comment: Are you trying to embed a tweet on your web page?

Comment: yes, from twitter.com,but there is thumbnails style twitter. I want last one tweet not all tweets. :)

Comment: @AshrafulHaque post your code and are you embedding your recent tweets, or a single tweet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one tweet, you can specify the amount of tweets you want in the HTML with the `data-tweet-limit` attribute, like so:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"
  data-widget-id="600720083413962752"
  href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev"
  data-tweet-limit="1">
  Tweets by @TwitterDev
</a>
```

If you want different behaviour than the embedded version of a feed (which is what you are using now, I think), you have to use the Twitter API. This means you have to make http requests (AJAX) to the Twitter servers.

To be able to do this you'll need to authenticate your website (application) with Twitter.

If you are willing to get it to work, you'll have to look at the Twitter REST API documentation.